# Форматирование при выводе decimal

Tags: c#

Возможно ли вывести `decimal` группируя цифры по разрядам с разделителем пробелом? 
Если число 0 - то выводит `0,00`, если `12321,12` - `12 321,12`
Пробую вот так

```
string dtos = number.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var format = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
format.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

Console.WriteLine(123456789.ToString("#,#.00", format));
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/OYls4N)

Comment: Вот так работает `"#,0.00"` но разделитель точка, а не запятая

Comment: Все понял - надо не `InvariantCulture`